# TypeError: $.ui and $element.dialog is undefined

Tags: 8, javascript

I have been handed a site to work on. It's on 8.5.1. The site was working. However, I cannot make changes on certain configs. For example, the dialog boxes for the views do not open anymore. I keep getting the following js error under the console.

I do not want to revert the database back to a working condition since the client would lose their data.

Update: The dialog box does work very very random.

[image]

Comment: No need to switch the database back. Seems there's a JS library missing. Most likely jQuery UI. Try to add it back. And just for clarification: You of course already have run the database updates and flushed all caches? If not, try that, too

Comment: @leymannx thank you so much for the quick response. I forgot to mention that I'm still very new to Drupal. How do I update the database? And where would I add the jQuery UI?

Comment: @Maria backup your DB first, then go to `www.yourwebsite.com/update.php`

Comment: `And where would I add the jQuery UI?` @Maria might aswell update Drupal Core to the latest 8.6.1, If you have any missing core files, this will fix your issue. Remember to run update.php after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping. 
I informed of the senior development of your suggestions. He was able to find the issue. Font Awesome module was installed incorrectly, he also updated to the latest core. We've uninstall Font Awesome and migrated to using Font Awesome CDN.